# HMR for Webpack 5 module federation

Tags: webpack, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

for 23 may 2021 I doesn't see hmr implementation for module federation.

As mentioned in this issue it will be implemented not soon.
Also in this issue was link for voting for hmr for module federation - webpack roadmap (**https://webpack.js.org/vote/**).

> https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11182

My question is - does anyone implement hmr already with webpack 5:

1. Maybe by forking webpack-hot-middleware and webpack-dev-middleware
2. Maybe it already implemented
3. Maybe someone has already implemented it with livereload tool

Any help or implementation would be great!

Thank you in advance.